# How does the shell script variable, that holds a command, work?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm trying to create an auto-compiling script that will compile programs from source, whenever I boot up my computer. It currently goes roughly like this (I can't remember the exact syntax):

```
VAR=$(sudo git pull)

if (VAR = "Nothing to update")

{

#do nothing

}

else {

#compile package

}
```

Will this work?
I'm wondering whether sudo git pull is called during VAR=$ or the if statement.

Comment: Your script has many errors. And you haven't even tried it. Please do your own research before posting.

Comment: @Mikel Yes, I realize this. I do have the script working, using the proper if statement, I'm just AFK right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command is only called during the initial command substitution, i.e. `VAR=$(sudo git pull)`.

You can easily test this.

```
$ VAR=$(touch foo; echo bar)
$ echo $VAR
bar
$ ls -l foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 me me 0 Dec  7 16:28 foo
```

You can see that I've created a file `foo`, and the output of the command substitution (`bar`) has been assigned to `$VAR`.

Now wait a minute and access the variable again.

```
$ echo $VAR
bar
$ ls -l foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 me me 0 Dec  7 16:28 foo
```

You can see that the modification time of `foo` has not changed.